# How to add members to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, colors, uislider

So I'm trying to use this library in a project of mine: [Color Slider](https://github.com/gizmosachin/ColorSlider) and I'm following the instructions. It states that

```
self.colorSlider = ColorSlider()
self.colorSlider.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 150)
self.view.addSubview(self.colorSlider)
```

is an appropriate way to add the colorSlider member. When I try this code, I get the error :

```
"[name of View Controller] does not have a member named colorSlider"
```

What exactly am I doing wrong and how would I go about fixing it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try the solution now, just adjust the frame, this solution works, without a hitch, I'll give you instructions to test it

Comment: Also, you don't have to add this as a POD, it's probably going to be much much easier if you just pull it into your application by dragging the file "ColorSlider.swift" into your project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to first declare the variable, something like this:

```
var colorSlider = ColorSlider()
```

I just added this to a project, and it works like butter when I first declare the variable, the view controller definitely finds it

see the full viewController version:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    var colorSlider: ColorSlider!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        colorSlider = ColorSlider(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 150))
        view.addSubview(self.colorSlider)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

If you want to test this, just make a new project in XCode, a swift project for a "Tabbed Application". Replace all the information in the FirstViewController with the last solution I've posted above, the solution right above this named "FirstViewController" and you can try it yourself!

Okay, so with Storyboards:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var colorSlider: ColorSlider!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

And the setup, it looks like this:

[image]

So, this was a quick and simple typcasting of the UIView in the storyboard that supplies its view to the FirstViewController. As you can see, all I did was select the "View" of the "First Scene" and then in the "class" dropdown box, I just changed this from a UIView to a ColodSlider, this is basically a typecast with Storyboards. I don't use storyboards, ever, so the next best bet is to add another UIView to the "First Scene" and then resize it, once you have the size you want, then you just go to the class dropdown box again like I explained above and you select "ColorSlider" and you'll have a color slider in the view with the BIG VIEW, the main view, still being a UIView.

Comment: That works great! Just one more question while I have you, let's say I don't want to add it through the cgrectmake function. How would I be able to do it through main.storyboard. To be more specific, how would I be able to add it through the interface builder.

Comment: one sec, let me try it out, I don't use storyboards, but lets see if we can hack this

Comment: okay, so this looks terrible, but it's how you do it, lol, I'll fix it up, but you'll get the point, look at the answer in 2 minutes

Comment: and in fact, I just fixed it for you

Comment: ill post a gist with the contents of the storyboard, I'm not sure this will help, but here it is, and if you want to use it, just save this as "Main.storyBoard" and it should work: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6744141a79a4633e8b40

Comment: No problem, and try the gist if you get stuck, I just downloaded it and resaved it as Main.storyboard and it works, good luck!